# Import Txt file to access database

Tags: c#

i have a txt file with format

```
10000025|246|31032017|00|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|R
10000025|246|31032017|01|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|R
10000025|246|31032017|02|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|R
10000025|246|31032017|03|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|R
```

i want import to access database using C# code 
If someone has a clue about how to perform something like this, i would be grateful !

Comment: Did you see this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e676b1a-793e-44fb-b4d8-c4e704d679d6/importing-text-files-into-ms-access-data-tablefield-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is any need to use c# sort of thing in this scenario. You can accomplish this task by using an excel sheet. Copy the whole txt file and paste it into the excel sheet, once done Select the header of the cell in which you copied the text (Lets say 'A'). Now in the top menu navigate to Data Tab and select "Text to Columns". A dialogue will appear where you can select Delimited (which is default selection) and click next there you will find the delimiters section where you can specify your delimiter like comma, semi colon, etc. In your case the separator is pipe character '|' so you can specify the pipe character in a text box given in the delimiter list.

Once done click next and finish you will get the data in a column and row form exactly what you were looking for now you can import the data to sql, access or to what ever you want take a look at this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Exchange-copy-import-export-data-between-Excel-and-Access-409c27cc-c69d-461d-a74c-35392a68ed53?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) to know how to import data from excel to access

I am attaching following screen shots

1. Picture of text data being copied in excelwith header selected
2. Screen shot of delimiter screen where you will specify the pipe character

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Screen shot of delimiter screen where you will specify the pipe character]